# Finding the remote that I need to pull rebase from

Tags: git

So we have a master and I created a branch form it and did a checkout on my branch
then I said `git pull --rebase`

and I got the message:

> There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please
>   specify which branch you want to rebase against. See git-pull(1) for
>   details
>
> ```
> git pull <remote> <branch>
> ```
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch

and then I did a `git remote -v` and I got back links like this:

```
origin  http://github.blah.com/masterLink.git (fetch)
origin  http://github.blah.com/masterLink.git (push)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a branch and it doesn't have any remote to pull from.

If all you want to do is rebase the master branch, you will need to do `git rebase origin/master`  This will get you the updates from master.

Comment: Ok thanks I did, now getting this: fatal: 'origin/master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you want to rebase origin/master.  As you have no remote branch that your created one refers to, pulling does not work.  Corrected my answer.